# Show on Scroll and Fade Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, scroll, show, fade

At the moment my code is this

```
    myID = document.getElementById("responsive-menu-button");

`enter code here`var myScrollFunc = function() {
  var y = window.scrollY;
  if (y >= 200) {
    myID.className = "bottomMenu show"
  } else {
    myID.className = "bottomMenu hide"
  }
};

window.addEventListener("scroll", myScrollFunc);
```

but at the moment it just shows and hides the DIV. I am wanting to add a fade affect such as `.fadeIn();` but i cant get this working at all within chromes development tool in the code snippet.

Any ideas? All the scripts with '$' in then seem to not work in chromes code snippet tester.

Thanks

Comment: Have you included jQuery? How did you try `.fadeIn()`? Note that `myID` is not a jQuery object so `.fadeIn()` doesn't work directly with it.

Comment: Hi, I am now finding and trying some jQuery scripts, will post later with my issues

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using simple CSS and js

CSS is `#responsive-menu-button{transition: all ease .6s;}`

And JavaScript

```
if (y >= 200) {
   myID.className = "bottomMenu"
   myID.style.opacity='.1';
   setTimeout(function(){myID.style.display='none'},600);
} 
else {
  myID.className = "bottomMenu"
  myID.style.display='';
  myID.style.opacity='1';
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to paste me some full Jquery code that will work with this? With editing little CSS? I have found some online but some just don't work as expected, let me find one and i will post the code and what i am having issue with :)

Comment: if(y>=200){ $('#responsive-menu-button').fadeOut();} else {$('#responsive-menu-button').fadeIn();}